# Alternative (LED?) for F25T8/350BL fluorescent tube

Tags: led, uv, fluorescent-lamp

I have a bug light that uses a couple of F25T8/350BL fluorescent tubes. The bulbs are on their way out, and the price for replacements is ridiculous.

They are about 18" in length, and 1" in diameter (T8).

Do LEDs with the same wavelength exist that I could use to attract the bugs?

Comment: Note that product recommendations are *not done* on this site, so questions directly asking for them are likely to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The wavelength of the light from such fluorescent tubes is about 350 - 360 nm. LEDs with that wavelength exist and can be googled easily; you could find and try a few, preferably high-power ones, and see what the insects think. They could be expensive, I don't know.

The LEDs' form factor and power requirements will be very  different from those of the tubes, but maybe somebody somewhere has made a direct LED-based replacement for the tubes.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a premade solution, but am able to handle the through hole LEDs (my eyes can't work on SMD!). I have googled some, and found 20ma, so if I did have a 100 of them, it is only a couple of amps.

Comment: @Alan: I'd try a few first, to see if they are bright enough to be interesting for the bugs. Also, a new bug light may be cheaper, I don't know. Don't forget to accept the answer (if you accept the answer).